# Converting String to Double with TableSource, Table or DataSet object in Java

Tags: java, apache-flink, data-conversion

I have imported data from a CSV file into Flink Java. One of the attributes I had to import as string (attribute `Result`) because of parsing errors. Now I want to convert the String to a Double. But I dont know how to do this with a object of the TableSource, Table or DataSet class. See my code below for this.

I've looked into flink documentation and tried some solutions with Map and FlatMap classes. But I did not find the solution for this.

```
        BatchTableEnvironment tableEnv = BatchTableEnvironment.create(fbEnv);

//Get H data from CSV file.
TableSource csvSource = CsvTableSource.builder()
                .path("Path")
                .fieldDelimiter(";")
                .field("ID", Types.INT())
                .field("result", Types.STRING())
                .field("unixDateTime", Types.LONG())
                .build();

   // register the TableSource
        tableEnv.registerTableSource("HTable", csvSource);

        Table HTable = tableEnv.scan("HTable");

        DataSet<Row> result = tableEnv.toDataSet(HTable, Row.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work to use a combination of [replace](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/functions.html#string-functions) and [cast](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/functions.html#type-conversion-functions) to convert the strings to doubles, as in "SELECT id, CAST(REPLACE(result, ',', '.') AS DOUBLE) AS result, ..." or the equivalent using the table API.